# Div not expanding with pictures

Tags: html, css

Okay so first off i've tried the overflow:hidden; but it didnt work so basically this is what my div is looking but when i add more images to it the div does not expand with it.

What the div looks like
  [image]

```css
.working{
    width: 600px;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: #ECECEC;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-width: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="working">



<p align: left; style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: #39F51B; display: block;">    <img src="img/shopify.jpg" align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
Shopify dropshipping</p>

<p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/code.png"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Coding </p>

<p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/ads.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Advertisement </p>
 <p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/amazon.png"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Amazon Mechanical Turk </p>
 <p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/fiverr.png"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Fiverr </p>
 <p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/foap.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Sell your photos </p> 
     <p align: left; style=" font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/pocketflip.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">PocketFlip</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not able to see any issues in "Run code snippet" and jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have a fixed height.
Try removing `height:2000px`.

```css
.working{
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #ECECEC;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-width: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="working">



<p align: left; style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: #39F51B; display: block;">    <img src="img/shopify.jpg" align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
Shopify dropshipping</p>

<p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/code.png"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Coding </p>

<p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/ads.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Advertisement </p>
 <p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/amazon.png"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Amazon Mechanical Turk </p>
 <p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/fiverr.png"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Fiverr </p>
 <p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/foap.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Sell your photos </p> 
     <p align: left; style=" font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/pocketflip.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">PocketFlip</p>
<p align: left; style=" font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/pocketflip.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">PocketFlip</p>
<p align: left; style=" font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/pocketflip.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">PocketFlip</p>
<p align: left; style=" font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/pocketflip.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">PocketFlip</p>
<p align: left; style=" font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/pocketflip.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">PocketFlip</p><p align: left; style=" font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/pocketflip.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">PocketFlip</p>

    </div>
```

Comment: I tried to remove max height but nothing is happening, the height won't expand no where after 2000px

Comment: I meant to say height instead of max height

Answer (score 0):

Removing `height:2000px;` and add `height:auto;`. It will solve your height problem. Height will increase when you add new `div` or `p` in it.

```css
.working{
    width: 600px;
    height:auto;
    background-color: #ECECEC;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-width: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="working">



<p align: left; style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: #39F51B; display: block;">    <img src="img/shopify.jpg" align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
Shopify dropshipping</p>

<p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/code.png"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Coding </p>

<p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/ads.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Advertisement </p>
 <p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/amazon.png"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Amazon Mechanical Turk </p>
 <p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/fiverr.png"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Fiverr </p>
 <p align: left; style="clear: left; display: block; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/foap.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Sell your photos </p> 
     <p align: left; style=" font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: black;"><img src="img/pocketflip.jpg"  align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">PocketFlip</p>
     <p align: left; style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: #39F51B; display: block;">    <img src="img/shopify.jpg" align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
Testing 1</p>
<p align: left; style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: #39F51B; display: block;">    <img src="img/shopify.jpg" align="middle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
Testing 2</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: What are you getting after adding `height:auto;` ?

Comment: Nothing, it stays the same. I'm not sure if my CSS is being updated

Comment: Can either share your updated code or can you refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/733fkz27/)